# A rectangle ABCD is given. n different points are chosen between A and B. Similarly, m different points are chosen on the side AD.

Tags: geometry

A rectangle ABCD (5 units x 4 units) is given.  On the side AB, n different points are chosen strictly between A and B.  Similarly, m different points are chosen on the side AD between A and D.  Lines are drawn from the points parallel to the sides.  How many rectangles are formed in this way?

Is the answer to be mC2*nC2?

Comment: I would say $(m+2){m\choose2}(n+2){n\choose2}$, assuming the sides of the original rectangle are counted.

Comment: "how many rectangles" is open to interpretation. If we look at the case $m = n = 1$, our rectangle is divided into four disjoint sub-rectangles, like panes of a window, so the answer might be "four". On the other hand, there's still the original rectangle (made up of four panes), two tall thin rectangles, and two wide short rectangles  (each made up of two panes), so one might also say $4+1+4 = 9$. As  @TonyK observes, in the latter case, there are $S = {{m+2} \choose 2}$ ways to pick the vertical edges, and $T = {{n+2} \choose 2}$ ways to pick horizontal ones, for a total of $ST$ rectangles.

Comment: I got confused by the \choose syntax! I meant ${m+2\choose2}{n+2\choose2}$, as @JohnHughes guessed.

Comment: I got confused by it too, and had to add a bunch of braces! Live and learn...

Comment: @TonyK Use `\binom{n}{k}` for $\binom{n}{k}$ The syntax is less confusing.

Comment: @JohnHughes See previous comment

Comment: Live and learn even more...thanks, Daniel!